# How to show linear operator $T:\ell_1\rightarrow \ell_1$ such that $\lVert T\rVert =1$ never attains norm.

Tags: functional-analysis

I have a question concerning the following proof. Let linear operator $T:\ell_1\rightarrow\ell_1$ be defined as
$$T(x_1,\ldots,x_i,\ldots)=((1-\frac{1}{1})x_1,\ldots,(1-\frac{1}{i})x_i,\ldots)$$
I have been able to show that $\lVert T\rVert=1$, but have difficulties showing that there is no $x\in \ell_1$ with $\lVert x\rVert_1=1$ such that $\lVert 
Tx\rVert_1=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

If $0<a_i<b_i$ for all $i\in\mathbb N$, then

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i < \sum_{i=1}^\infty b_i$$

**Hint 2**:

Take any $x$, and write out the definition of $\|x\|_1$ and $\|Tx\|_1$.